# Perforce Streams: Difference between merge-down and copy-from?

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between `merge-down` and `copy-from` in `perforce` streams? 
Both will get the changes from one branch to other, right ?

Can we edit the stream views once created? i have created 'main' stream with views below.

View:
share temp/...
share ktm/...

I have a child stream 'ptb_stream' created from 'main'.I have updated the views below for child stream.

View:
import temp/...
share ktm/...

which creates my child steam with only 'ktm' in it. Now, i just made the change in my child stream view 'ptb_stream' as below.

View:
import temp/...
import ktm/...

when i do that i am still seeing the folders in that child stream view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is, that if you work on a less stable branch than your product branch (e.g. main) and you merge all other changes form the product branch into your branch.

If you did your work (including all testing) you are allowed to copy your changes up to main. Since you merged and integrated all other changes a pure copy will do and no merge is required.

Comment: okay, thanks schorsch. I have one more question which i updated above can you please check?

Comment: @kunal Your second question, I can not answer. For the next time, please ask a second question, because now if someone is reading your question my answer seams quite unrelated. It is better to have two questions and one is answered and closed (you can close your question if you think it is answered be clicken on the hock left to the answer).

Comment: asked the question @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687018/perforce-streams-can-we-edit-streams-in-perforce please check