# Perforce streams: Can we edit streams in perforce

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

Can we edit the stream views once created? i have created 'main' stream with views below.

View: share temp/... share ktm/...

I have a child stream 'ptb_stream' created from 'main'.I have updated the views below for child stream.

View: 
import temp/... 
share ktm/...

which creates my child steam with only 'ktm' in it. Now, i just made the change in my child stream view 'ptb_stream' as below.

View: 
import temp/... 
import ktm/...

when i do that i am still seeing the folders in that child stream view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can modify stream views.

> i am still seeing the folders in that child stream view.

I am unable to parse this sentence.  Do you mean:

- You are still seeing the folders in client views generated from this stream
- You are still seeing the folders in branch views generated between these streams
- You are still seeing files in the depot location corresponding to this stream path
- You are still seeing files in the workspace location corresponding to this stream path
- You are seeing the wrong files in the workspace location corresponding to this stream path

Some of these are expected and necessary behavior, some of them would indicate that something has gone wrong.  Which are you talking about?  (And for the last two -- did you `p4 sync` after modifying the stream?)

Comment: 3rd one -> 'You are still seeing files in the depot location corresponding to this stream path' . Yes ,i am still seeing the files in depot location of the streams. i modified one of the child stream path from 'share' to 'import'. In that case i should not see the files in depot of that child stream right? And how can we see the branch views created from streams?

Comment: Don't use the depot view with streams; it lies.  Sync your client and look at what's in your workspace.  You should see that what's in your workspace matches the import, and the depot files you were looking at aren't mapped anywhere (they are no longer part of any stream view, even though they still exist in the depot).

Comment: Ohh Okay.. Yes, in workspace those files are seen as imported files. if those files will not go away from depot users will get confused right ? We cant remove them permanently ?

Comment: Don't use P4V's depot view with streams ever.  In fact it's ideal to just not use P4V with streams IMO.  :)  You can always obliterate the files to get rid of them permanently, but it's better to just interact with streams via the workspace view, NEVER the depot view.

Comment: Sam,thanks for your answers. I tired editing the stream but not able to see the files in work space when i do 'Get latest revision' with p4v. Steps 1) I created a child stream from parent (which has everything shared share/...) 2) While creating i marked some of the parths with import and some with share (Consider folder share /temp/... import /bar/...) which is working as expected,which creates child stream with only temp and workspace with both 'temp' , 'bar' folders.3) I tried to edit the child view by marking 'bar' folder to 'share' and then synced the work. But still no files from 'bar'.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing some changes from your parent stream.  Whenever that's the case, the fix is the same: merge from parent, resolve, submit.

Comment: Basically if we edit the stream view from 'import' to 'share' the files from main should be visible in child stream in depot right ? sounds like once we create the stream views we cant modify it. But i am not sure about it :(

Comment: I gave you the answer and you ignored it: merge from parent, resolve, submit.  Since the files are in a "share" path they now receive changes from their parent when you integrate.  Did you integrate when you added the "share" path?  No?  Time to do that.  :)  When you first create a stream this is included in the initial "populate" command, but from that point on you need to integrate to pick up new changes.  This is exactly the same as "classic" branching in Perforce (or in any other tool).

Comment: Yeah, Will d o that. Thanks :)